# Handlebar Complex Data structure

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have currently got multiple partials and they are using high level data structures. For each page, i have its own data structure, so i can get page specific and one component specific json structure.

**full.json**

```
{
    "paragraph":{
        "lorem": "blah blah blah"
    },
    "somethingelse":{
        "lorem": "blah blah"
    }
    "partialthree":{
        "lorem": "blah blah"
    }
    page_one: {
        "title": "blah blah",
        "somethingelse": {
            "lorem": "something completely different."
        }
    }    
}
```

**comp/partial_one.hbs**

```
{{#paragraph}}
    <p>{{lorem}}</p>
{{/paragraph}}
```

Output: `<p>blah blah blah</p>`

**comp/partial_two.hbs**

```
{{#somethingelse}}
    <div>{{lorem}}</div>
{{/somethingelse}}
```

Output: `<div>blah blah</div>`

**comp/partial_three.hbs**

```
{{#partialthree}}
    <p>{{lorem}}</p>
    {{> comp/partial_two }}
{{/partialthree}}
```

Output (note, partial_two didnt load due to the data structure is now `partialthree.somethingelse` (which doesnt exist): `<p>blah blah</p>`

**page/page_one.hbs**

```
{{#page_one}}
    {{> comp/partial_three }}
    <div>{{title}}</div>
    {{> comp/partial_two }}
{{/page_one}}
```

Output:

```
<div>blah blah</div>
<div>something completely different.</div>
```

**Question**: Is it possible for `page_one` and `partial_three` handlebar templates which have partials inside them to default if it cannot find the data.

**Question**: Is this the correct way of handling data in handlebar.

**Note: I CANNOT CHANGE THE FULL.JSON STRUCTURE. ITS ALWAYS COMPONENTS AND THEN PAGES.**

Comment: Iterate through object properties and use some kind of lookup or just if statements to render templates based on property existance.